# Some other domain is redirecting to my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, httpresponse, http-redirect

My website was running just fine then one day i found some other domain was redirecting to my site. whenever someone go for that domain url that redirects to my site.

the problem is the other domain is not even registered. that was registered years ago and that owner had clients on that. but he gave to that domain and domain is free since then. but now a days that is automatically redirecting to mine. whenever my posts update, RSS feed is sent to that domain's client.

the other domain owner has nothing to do with that because he is no longer the owner and can not help.

I tried to update `.htacces` and defined the rules to not accept that url but instead it always show error that too many redirects because if that domain is restricted it tries again and again due to which my site goes down..

how could i overcome this issue?

Comment: Do whois search to see the new owner of that domain, and contact him to stop redirect ?

Comment: This is not a "redirection". It most likely is an old DNS entry that points to some IP address which has been assigned to you in the mean time. Little you can do about that, since it is not your entry. On the other hand: why is that an issue for you? You publish thinks, you should be glad for every client accessing your site...

Comment: The old owner of other site having issues. his old clients get RSS feed from my site. and they disturb him. and i also dont want to get traffic from unknown sources

Comment: I had similar issue when one client had spam websites linked to his website, so we decided to rewrite 403 (Forbidden) all those domains. You can try that.